# Problem giving permissions to delete firestore rules

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-security

Currently I have the following problems ... I try to give permissions to delete and it is not possible, it gives me insufficient permissions

```
rules_version = '2';

function isAdmin(request) {
  return request.auth.uid == 'UID-ADMIN'
}
function sameUser(request, resource) {
  return request.auth.uid == resource.data.uid
}

match /accounts/{account} {
 allow create: if request.auth.uid != null;
 allow read, delete: if sameUser(request, resource) || isAdmin(request);
}

// return Missing or insufficient permissions. Only try delete
```

I do not understand why with this the reading does it without problems, but when trying to eliminate I receive the error message ...

I tried...

```
// return Missing or insufficient permissions.

allow read, delete: if sameUser(request, resource) || isAdmin(request);
// -
allow delete: if sameUser(request, resource));
// -
allow delete: if request.auth.uid == resource.data.uid
```

Now, why with the same rule applied lets me read, but won't let me delete? It's wrong?

Here is the error I always receive:

```
FirebaseError: Missing or insufficient permissions.
    at new FirestoreError (webpack-internal:///./node_modules/@firebase/firestore/dist/index.cjs.js:351:28)
    at JsonProtoSerializer.fromRpcStatus (webpack-internal:///./node_modules/@firebase/firestore/dist/index.cjs.js:15666:16)
    at JsonProtoSerializer.fromWatchChange (webpack-internal:///./node_modules/@firebase/firestore/dist/index.cjs.js:16179:44)
    at PersistentListenStream.onMessage (webpack-internal:///./node_modules/@firebase/firestore/dist/index.cjs.js:12804:43)
    at eval (webpack-internal:///./node_modules/@firebase/firestore/dist/index.cjs.js:12733:30)
    at eval (webpack-internal:///./node_modules/@firebase/firestore/dist/index.cjs.js:12773:28)
    at eval (webpack-internal:///./node_modules/@firebase/firestore/dist/index.cjs.js:1694:20)
```

Comment: Please edit your question to also include the minimal code with which you can reproduce the question. Be sure to make sure that the code shows the authentication state of the user right before you try to delete the data, for example by `console.log(firebase.auth().currentUser.uid)`.

Comment: Hi @Gabriela if you could please edit your question and include the whole error message as well, would be interesting for the Community to understand the exact error that you are facing.

Comment: hi! @FrankvanPuffelen thanks. I have verified that it existed `console.log(firebase.auth().currentUser.uid)`. Indeed if it returns the uid correctly when trying to delete.

Comment: Hi @Gabriela indeed, it seems correct. Considering that, in case you are still facing the issue, I would recommend you to contact the [Firebase Support](https://firebase.google.com/support) directly, so they can assist you with it. (They have a free option to contact them)

Comment: have you ever figured this thing out ?